# What are the sources or clock for Linux time functions (time , gettimeofday ...)

Tags: c, linux-kernel

What are the sources or clock of Linux time functions ?

Are all (time , gettimeofday ...) getting updated clock values from reading same hardware component? Or are they all just retrieving some current time value maintained by Kernel?

Any of these function will read directly from BIOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies depending on a large number of factors including what hardware is available, whether time synchronization is in use, and a number of other factors. On typical modern hardware, the TSC or HPET is read and scaled according to factors maintained by the kernel's timekeeping system.